# $\ A+A=\{3i,3+2i,3+4i\}$. find A

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone help me and answer this exercise of complex analysis? I don't know how to try to resolve this because I have never seen an exercise like this.

Comment: Are you certain that it isn't $\{3,3+2i, 3+4i\}$?

Comment: **Hint.** Clearly, $|A|=2$.  If $A=\{z,z+d\}$ for some $z,d\in\mathbb{C}$, then $A+A=\{2z,2z+d,2z+2d\}$, which is an arithmetic progression with common difference $d$.  (It is highly possible Arthur is right and you made a typographical error.)

Comment: Thanks to all for help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Let $z = a+bi \in A$. Then $z+z \in A+A=\{3i,3+2i,3+4i\}$. This gives you 3 choices for $z$.

Since $A$ must have at least two elements, this gives you 4 possible choices for $A$, and you simply check which ones work.

You can reduce the case by case analysis by showing that $A$ has exactly two elements, and showing that these correspond to $z+z$ having the smallest/largest imaginary part.

Comment: As written, this is impossible. For a two-element $A$, we get that $A+A$ consists of three collinear points. These three points are not collinear.

Comment: Maybe the exercise is wrong and the first element is 3 and not 3i, after all i understand your explanations, Thanks to all for help me :D